# MKMapView adding specific locations

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mkmapview

Could anyone please tell how to add some specific locations on MapView(MKMapView). I made mapView which shows my current location, I also added searchBar for searching address's locations. For now, this works fine, but I also want for MapView to show me some specific locations (for example: hospitals nearby)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get the coordinates for the location you want to show on the map. Have an array of annotations with each annotation having the coordinate you want to show. then make use of the method

```
[urMapView addAnnotations:urAnnotationsArray];
```